# Scan-based operations Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Looking at the first paper on RDDs/Apache Spark, I found a statement saying that "RDDs degrade gracefully when there is not enough memory to store them, as long as they are only being used in scan-based operations"

What are scan-based operations in the context of RDDs and which of the [Transformations in Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) are scan-based operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scan based operations are basically all the operations that require evaluating the predicate on an RDD.

In other terms, each time your create an RDD or a DataFrame in which you need to compute a *predicate* like performing a filter, map on a case class, per example, or even explain method will be considered as a scan based operation.

To be more clear, let's review the definition of a predicate.

A predicate or a functional predicate is a logical symbol that may be applied to an object term to produce another object term.

Functional predicates are also sometimes called *mappings*, but that term can have other meanings as well.

Example :

```
// scan based transformation
rdd.filter(!_.contains("#")) // here the predicate is !_.contains("#")

// another scan based transformation
rdd.filter(myfunc) // myfunc is a boolean function

// a third also trivial scan based transformation followed by a non scan based one.
rdd.map(myfunc2) 
   .reduce(myfunc3)
```

If you want to understand how spark internals work, I suggest that you watch the [presentation](https://spark-summit.org/2014/talk/a-deeper-understanding-of-spark-internals) made by Databricks about the topics

Comment: That means that all Transformations in Spark are scan-based operations. Can you give some examples of Spark operations that aren't scan-based?

Comment: I didn't say that. What I said it that each time there is a predicate to calculate, the operation is scan based.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. Can you kindly give an example of a transformation with predicate evaluation and one without it? I am (mostly) unfamiliar with Spark API atm and an example would help :) Thanks

Comment: @MB_CE I have edited the answer. Finding a non based transformation (not actions) example is actually quite tricky and difficult.

Comment: @eliasah what about methods like cache and unpersist? I don't think they count as transformations or actions, but they seem like an example of *something* that's not scan-based.

Comment: Cache and unpersist aren't transformations nor actions but persistence methods. The `cache` method is a shorthand for using the default storage level, which is `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY`

Comment: @eliasah How is the reduce transformation on rdd.map not scan-based? Thanks for the reference, I will take a look :)

Comment: It just apply a monad operation on the mapped RDD from the step before.